# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, remix, esbuild, npm-link

#### Edit

So, what turned out to be the problem? I had two instances of React and ReactDOM contributing to the served bundle of `applicationB`. I was misled in diagnosing the problem-space and therefore the question(s)/appeal raised below is a little all-over-the-place. What should be taken away, in the hope it may help someone else in this position:

- The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')` relates to there being two copies of React loaded into the output bundle of `applicationB`. But why are there two copies?

  - To start, `applicationB` is a Remix application. `packageA` is a React Component that makes use of esbuild in its build chain.
  - Through investigating, I discovered there was a discrepancy in the support `Remix` had for `esbuild`:

    - `esbuild` [added support for the React 17 JSX Transform](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/334).
    - `Remix` was perhaps not aware of this update and coped with `esbuild`'s lack of support for JSX Automatic Runtime by using a **shim** for the React import. This resulted in issues being raised:

      - [Inability to consume external React Component Library in Remix project due to multiple copies of React error](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/2987#issuecomment-1156615850).
      - [Inability to package React Component library with esbuild due to multiple copies of React error.](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/475#issuecomment-985957709)
    - `Remix` recognised the fault with the **shim** and included a [solution in release v1.7.0](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/releases).
- In `applicationB` I was consuming all `Remix` dependencies as versioned `^1.4.1`. I bumped them up to `1.7.0`. All my troubles dissolved.

#### Background:

I am trying to test an npm package (`packageA`) I am developing locally. It is a React Component that manages an animation using gsap. I am consuming it in `applicationB`--itself is a Remix app,--through the use of npm link. However, I get the following error when trying to introduce `packageA` to `applicationB`:

```
// 1. warning logged to console
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at ki (react.development.js:1634:21)
    at Mk (PackageAComponent.tsx:26:3)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26560:12)
```

```js
const PackageAComponent = (props: Props) => {

// 1. culprit line of failure
  useEffect(() => {
    ... stuff happening
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

##### Relevant Notes

###### packageA output of "npm ls react react-dom"

- react@18.2.0
- react-dom@18.2.0

###### applicationB output of "npm ls react react-dom"

- react@18.2.0
- react-dom@18.2.0

I am unsure what other data would be relevant to provide and how best to troubleshoot this so that I may provide more helpful insights. Sorry team.

Comment: React is null. It looks like one app isn't built/bundled with an instance of React? We would need to see more of your project setup/configuration/etc and what you are doing (*i.e. reproduction steps*) to likely provide any more insight/assistance.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the reply! 

I am using esbuild to bundle `packageA` for the browser. `applicationB` is a Remix application. Because `packageA` is dependant on browser based APIs to run, I handle its rendering as recommended [here](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/constraints#rendering-with-browser-only-apis). For reproduction: 1) I generate a build of `packageA`. 2) I run `npm link ../packageA` from `applicationB`. 3) I boot up a local dev server in `applicationB`, itself hosting a React Application that consumes `packageA`.

Comment: Were you able to find any solutions to this @slackermorris